# The element is obscured(Server did not provide stack information) automation in edge browser with selenium

Tags: selenium

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is obscured (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information).
This code is working fine for chrome and firefox but not with edge browser.

```
     `public class Login {
            public WebDriver driver;
            By userName = By.id("ctl14_UserName");
            By password = By.id("ctl14_Password");
            By login = By.id("ctl14_LoginButton");

            public Login(WebDriver driver) {
                this.driver = driver;
            }
            // Set password in username textbox
            public void setUserName(String strUserName) {   
                driver.findElement(userName).sendKeys(strUserName); 
            }
            // Set password in password textbox
            public void setPassword(String strPassword) {
                driver.findElement(password).sendKeys(strPassword);
            }
          public void clickMyaccount(){
               driver.findElement(myAccount).click();
            }
        // Click on login button
            public void clickLogin() {
                driver.findElement(login).click();

            }
        }
        //Test class
        public class AdminLogin extends BaseForDifferentLogins {
                 Login objLoginAdmin;
                 @Test(priority=0)
                    public void login() throws InterruptedException{
                      objLoginAdmin=new Login(driver); 
                      objLoginAdmin.clickMyaccount();
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                        objLoginAdmin.setUserName("superuser1");
                        objLoginAdmin.setPassword("superuser1");
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                        objLoginAdmin.clickLogin();
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                    }
        }`
```

Comment: For which element are you getting this error?

Comment: Chrome waits until page completely loads however edge (edgedriver) does not do that so if click event, loads page/changes DOM, wait for event to complete.  Refer http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp# for different wait types.

Comment: I'm not sure event completion is the problem (can be tested by enabling EdgePageLoadStrategy.Normal). In my case this started happening when edge started displaying the "Save password?" dialog on login.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using *webElement.click()* you can try to build *Actions* with *click* and do *perform*. Had the same issue on Edge and that did the trick for me:

`Actions actions = new Actions(webDriver);
actions.click(webElement).perform();`

Comment: Thank you for posting this.  This is exactly what worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

I have encountered the issue and tried several things to solve it:

- enabled EdgePageLoadStrategy.Normal - did not help;
- disabled the "save your password?" bubble. - did not help;
- normalized the zoom level to 100% - bingo / eureka. This solved the issue.

My test script is a bit more performance-oriented, so I had no desire to add additional objects / capabilties / options. If you want your test to be more deployable add registry editing capabilities to your selenium script. This can be a starter: http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/microsoft-edge-disable-zoom-reset-zoom-level-every-start/

Comment: The zoom level also fixed this for me

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue on the Edge browser. 
It was difficult to figure out what was actually wrong, since the issue seemed to appear/disappear from time to time in my case.
So at some point I decided to contact MS and created this ticket [question](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/14838046/)

Here Steven K mentioned that the obscured element error is most likely due to zoom level not being at 100% So I checked and indeed it was at 125% for some reason.
After I set it back to 100% the issue was resolved for me.

```
browser.send_keys [:control, '0']
```

I know this is a ruby+watir example, but I'm sure there is a similar Java trick for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this problem while testing Angular with Protractor in Microsoft Edge. 
What finally helped me was combining two workarounds:

1. Set browser zoom value to 100% explicitly in beforeEach function:
   `browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).sendKeys('0')
   .keyUp(protractor.Key.CONTROL).perform();`
2. Do click through browser actions: 
   `browser.actions().mouseMove(yourElementThatIsNotActuallyObscured).click().perform();`

Answer (score 0):

Resetting Zoom level to 100% will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void clickUntillNotObsecured(WebElement elementToClick) {
    boolean obsecuredThrown = true;
    int c=0;
    while (obsecuredThrown && c<30) {
        try {
            clickOnElement(elementToClick);             
            obsecuredThrown = false;
        } catch (WebDriverException e) {
            obsecuredThrown = true;
        }
        c++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the task with the Action chains in the python specially with Edge browser:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
button_xpath  = '//xapth...' 
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(button_xpath)
actionChains.move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

But sometimes Action chain does not finds the DOM element. Hence better option to use execute_script in following way which is compatible with all browsers:

```
button_xpath  = '//xapth...' 
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(button_xpath)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

Answer (score -1):

Even I faced same problem today running tests on Edge, But when I observed the problem, after which step it's failing just check it up, after that step give a time delay of 5 to 10 seconds, by doing this it solved my problem. And i got the same error many times while running in Edge at different part of my program, i just added time delay at all those steps, it solved my problem and now test successfully running on EDGE.

I added delay by using

`Thread.sleep(5000);`

just try this, if it doesn't work for you, I found one other solution if it's failing at the time of clicking, that is perform click operation using javascript.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfd"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

This solution I got from
https://softwaretestingboard.com/qna/363/word-around-for-edge-driver-click
https://softwaretestingboard.com/qna/745/excpetion-selenium-webdriverexception-element-obscured

First one worked for me.

Comment: I had the same error, but after observing what actually happened at the browser during execution, decided to catch the error & continue the execution. The Click action is working - so the error is misleading.

Comment: Yeh so... it's not the same problem, and it's bad-practice you are using there